# excel VBA using the "if function" in vba excel only show text in the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

first time asking here.

i'm trying to make work the next code in vba:

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("COMP 1").Range("M916").formula= "+IF(AG$19="""";"""";1)"`

The issue is that if a put just the **"+"** in the code, in the work sheet just apear the text like this:

And as you can see in the red circle, the option to show formulas is off, and int the green circles you can see that other formulas are working and showing the result:
[image]

But if i try to put **"=+"** or **"="** in the code the error 1004 pops out.

Btw sorry for my english, as is not my native lenguage

Comment: vba needs to be in en-usa format: `"=IF(AG$19="""","""",1)"`

Comment: All formulas begin with `=`.  When you start it with a `+`, Excel is treating the cell as text (since it's not a formula).  `=+` is supported only to be compatible with a spreadsheet application that hasn't existed for two decades.  (Lotus 1-2-3)

Comment: @ScottCraner `Range("M916").FormulaLocal = "=IF(....."` would allow you to use local separators wouldn't it?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes, I was too lazy to include the second option, as you would also need to know what `IF` is in the OP's language.  My guess is `Range("M916").FormulaLocal = "=SI(...` but that is only a guess.  It was easier just to make the OP change the `;` to `,` as they already translated the formula.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, You were really helpfull,